# Pull portions of data from a db field and create multiple variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

I'm converting MySQL data from one system to another, and the database structure is not quite the same. One database field contains multiple parameters in a format like this:

```
option1=value1
option2=value2
option3=value3
```

Yes, it is a text field with line breaks. I need to get the data (using PHP) from the one field and make variables out of it. For example, I need "option1=value1" converted to a variable $option1 that contains the value "value1".

I have pulled the data of this field into an array and tried imploding that data into a string that I could make variables from... but have had no luck. Either I wasn't doing it right or that's not the right direction to go.

I was trying something like this:

```
$string = implode("&",$array);
echo $string;
```

...but I just get a bunch of "Notice: Array to string conversion" messages along with an echo of "&Array" over and over. Help appreciated!

UPDATE:
For further explanation, I've realized that I need a two level array with the user ID (pulled from the same table as the option values noted above) in one array... then each of those IDs having a nested array containing the option values.

Comment: Is the data literally on separate lines like that, or does that represent several rows of data?  if you query the field, what does an example result look like when you `var_dump` it?

Comment: @cale_b I have updated the initial question... but to answer your question... I'm pulling a user ID along with this option field value into an array... and it looks like this (a piece of it at least):

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [uidNumber] => 1 [params] => access_optin=2 ) [1] => Array ( [uidNumber] => 1012 [params] => show_bio=1 show_url=1 show_picture=1 show_organization=1 ) [2] => Array ( [uidNumber] => 1003 [params] => access_optin=2 )`

So I need to get the 'params' value into a nested array.

Answer (score 2):

From your description

```
option1=value1
option2=value2
option3=value3
```

isn't an array, but a text field with line breaks. You should do

```
$myarray=explode("\n",$textfield);
```

to get a proper array.

From then on, your attempted solution seems to rely in converting that array into a query string you will pass with a GET request to another page. For that matter, you can implode the array using & as the glue.

However you also said that you need to convert array items into variables. For that purpose, you can create a new array in the form

```
$assocarray=[];
foreach($myarray as $item) {
  $keyvalue=explode('=',$item);
  $assocarray[$keyvalue[0]]=$keyvalue[1];
}
```

which will result in $assocarray being

```
Array [
    'option1' => value1,
    'option2' => value2,
    'option3' => value3,
];
```

So you could perform

```
extract($assocarray);
```

to get 3 variables called $option1, $option2 and $option3 in the global namespace.

Edit: I see that, for some reason, you have nested arrays. Something like

```
$myarray = Array [
                  Array [ 
                     "access_optin=2", 
                     "", 
                     ""
                  ],
                  Array [
                     "show_bio=1",  
                     "show_url=1", 
                     "show_picture=1", 
                     "show_organization=1", 
                     "access_optin=2", 
                     "access_jobtitle=0",  
                     "access_email=0"
                  ]
            ];
```

and the iteration should be

```
$assocarray=[];
foreach($myarray as $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $item) {
        $keyvalue=explode('=',$item);
        if(count($keyvalue)==2) $assocarray[$keyvalue[0]]=$keyvalue[1];
    }
}
```

Note that I'm validating the size of the $keyvalue array, because some not every value will have the name=value pattern.

**Second Edit**:

Since each $subarray represents a different user, you need to store the parsed key/value pair in a subarray too.

```
$assocarray=[];
foreach($myarray as $user => $subarray) {
    foreach($subarray as $item) {
        $keyvalue=explode('=',$item);
        if(count($keyvalue)==2) $assocarray[$user][$keyvalue[0]]=$keyvalue[1];
    }
}
```

This assumes your $user matches the user_id you need to set. Otherwise, you'll have to go a bit backwards to where you give form to the $myarray variable. I'm afraid you'll need to, because your example starts with zero and I bet your user_id doesn't.

Comment: closer, but not quite yet. The data was pulled already into an array so I started with:
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($options)) {
        $myarray[] = explode("\n", implode($rows));
    }

Now the options are in a regular array and no longer have the line break. The next part isn't working though...

    $assocarray = array();
    foreach($myarray as $item) {
 $keyvalue = explode("=", $item);
 $assocarray[$keyvalue[0]] = $keyvalue[1];
    }

Result:

   Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

...refers to exploding $keyvalue.

Comment: Please post a var dump of $myarray

Comment: It's very long but starts with...

`array(6206) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "access_optin=2" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(32) { [0]=> string(10) "show_bio=1" [1]=> string(10) "show_url=1" [2]=> string(14) "show_picture=1" [3]=> string(19) "show_organization=1" [4]=> string(14) "access_optin=2" [5]=> string(17) "access_jobtitle=0" [6]=> string(14) "access_email=0"`

Comment: It seems to have nested arrays. You'll need to iterate them using a second foreach.

Comment: sorry, but can you help me with how exactly to iterate this?

Comment: To explain further... I'm pulling this data (the text field with line breaks) for a bunch of users. I also need that user ID. So the more I process this, I need this to be a nested array with the first array containing the user IDs, then each ID having a nested array with the option values that we were already working with here. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: A print_r of the new $assocarray gives me:
`Array ( [access_optin] => 0 [show_bio] => 1 [show_url] => 1 [show_picture] => 1 [show_organization] => 1 [access_jobtitle] => 0 [access_email] => 0 [access_phone] => 0` ...and so on.

The problem is that it skipped key[0] in the array and it only pulled data into the new assocarray from key[1] and key[2].

Comment: Forgot to tag you in my new comment @amenadiel. Thanks!

Comment: It's not that it's skipping it. It's overwriting it. It seems that you have the same variable names over and over. So you need to make sure what do you want to do with those variables.

Comment: Yes, as noted yesterday, this is a database table containing option values for many different users. So each user has a field that contains the list of all of these options that have been set. They are not all set for each user, but each one will have the same option names used. So I DO need the "=" splitting the options into keys and values... BUT I need each db field of user options storing the values in an array like this for each user. Follow? I tried explaining this further yesterday but I'm thinking you did not see it... the comment that starts "To explain further...". Thanks!

Comment: Ok, edited again. Keep in mind that this time you won't be able to use extract since the key names are not unique. But you will end up with a nice key/value pair nested array.